# How to get the next element of a specific class in selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, reddit

I am a complete beginner to selenium. I would like to know, for example, when loading the reddit page, how to get all the titles of the reddit posts on that page. I know the HTML header for those is h2, and I know how to get the first header of the reddit site. However, how do you **switch to the next element of the same class** in order to grab it? I'm using python and selenium. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any code that you tried to do yourself.

Comment: Please be descriptive about your question. So someone could help you out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! See: [How do I do X?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253069/whats-the-appropriate-new-current-close-reason-for-how-do-i-do-x) The expectation on Stack Overflow is that the user asking a question not only does research to answer their own question but also shares that research, code attempts, and results. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: oh ok, sorry. I didn't know, i created my account yesterday

Comment: how do i mark my question as resolved?

Answer (score 0):

First you want to get all elements of your class (update myClass to the class you want):

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("myClass")
```

You then have all the elements of that class saved in an array. I'll let you try work out how to access the 2nd element from that.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, whenever I ran the python script, google chrome would just flash and would automatically minimize. Now, all of a sudden, running the script opens a new window for me, which I have to manually minimize. Is there a way to revert whatever I did so that opening a link in chrome will automatically minimize the new method? (no driver.minimize or --headless) Thank you.

Comment: it sounds like a different problem to your original issue. I suggest you start another question on Stack Overflow and add your code to the question so we can understand and fix the issue you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

For reddit specifically, to get a list of all the titles on the page, use `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".imors3-0.euspgB")` to get an array of all the titles on the page.

Comment: `imors3-0` and `euspgB` are dynamically generated classes. You should try to avoid them.

Answer (score 0):

The question is confusingly worded, but I think you just want to iterate through all elements on the page with an `h2` tag.

for example:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h2')
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need a simple example on how to iterate through the elements in the body, feel free to check out my mini project at https://github.com/kerwei/LimaSE_Scraper/blob/master/lima_scrape.py

Lines 113 - 114 would probably be of interest to you.

As pointed out in the previous answer:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath(pattern)
```

gets you all the target elements. Please pay attention to the (s) in element**s**. Thereafter, you only have to loop through the iterables returned by the method.